Tableau calculation (Price Percentage Difference)
Percentage Price difference over a time period.
I was trying to manage this calculation by my own, but I still can not figure it out. I would appreciate any help here.
At the first view, you can see how each brand performs over a time period.
I would like to put here one more column "Percent Difference" which does the following  "The [Price__List] with [Max Date] minus the [Price__List] with [Min date] divided by The [Price_List] with [Max Date]". Also the percentage difference within one time period.
The Max and Min Date for time period should be taken from the filter "Date lp".
Here are my calculations:
Price__List:
IFNULL((SUM([Price List])), PREVIOUS_VALUE(0))

Price Difference11:
(ZN([Price__List]) - LOOKUP(ZN([Price__List]), -1)) / 
ABS(LOOKUP((ZN([Price__List])), -1))

After an executing these two calculations, I get these views:
performing view:

percentage difference:

If I understand this right, Tableau calculates the percentage difference for each date. But I would like to see just one number per each brand.

Please share a Tableau Public workbook, it will help us to solve faster

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Your calculation is fine, remove the [DateLP] pill from your columns shelf.
If you need a percent diff for all the dates as well, I would suggest duplicating this worksheet as is, removing [DateLP] from one of them, then combining them both in a dashboard.
